# Is there a more appropriate to test if the constructor throws an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit.net, fluent-assertions

Normally you test, if an exception gets thrown in a certain method, as follows. 
I use **FluentAssertions**:

```
[Fact]
public void Exception_gets_thrown()
{
    // Arrange
    var foo = new Foo("validArgument");

    // Act/Assert
    foo.Invoking(f => f.Bar(null))            // null is an invalid argument
       .ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
}
```

But how to test, if an exception gets thrown in the constructor? 
I just did it like this, but is there maybe a more appropriate way
via **FluentAssertions**?

```
[Fact]
public void Constructor_throws_Exception()
{
    // Arrange
    Action a = () => new Foo(null);         // null is an invalid argument

    // Act/Assert
    a.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's exactly how you're supposed to test for exceptions and that's what `ShouldThrow<T>()`  and `ShouldNotThrow<T>()` were designed for in the first place. In fact, the `Invoking()` approach might be marked as obsolete in the next big version (2.0.0).

Comment: But is it the right way to test, if an exception gets thrown in the constructor? Via this action?

Comment: Shame about obsoleting the Invoking() approach. I find it far easier to read than the Action mechanism displayed in the second test above. Invoking keeps everything nicely together so the intent is obvious.

Comment: @ebeen I usually just use the [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))] when testing exceptions being thrown from the constructor. Given that there is only one line in the test, the exception can only be thrown from there.

Comment: @JackHughes The reason why we introduced the Invoking() and ShouldThrow<T>() variants is to get rid of those [ExpectedException] attributes. The Unit Test project for Metro apps doesn't even support that attribute anymore.

Comment: Not a huge fan of [ExpectedException] either... I just prefer it to using the Action syntax from FA in that very specific case. I use FA everywhere else :)

Comment: The Invoking construct is a nice API IMHO BTW :)

Comment: @DennisDoomen - That's Customer Service!! :)

Comment: We're about to release 2.1, and it's still in ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I added a helper method like the below for use when testing constructors:

```
static Action Constructor<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    return () => func();
}
```

which I then use like this:

```
Constructor(() => new Foo("bar", null))
.ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>()
.And
.ParamName
.Should()
.Be("baz");
```

I know it's a matter of personal taste, but I find this a bit cleaner than needing to declare and assign a delegate first.

This would make the code in the original question look like this:

```
[Fact]
public void Constructor_throws_Exception()
{    
    // Act/Assert
    Constructor(() => new Foo(null)).ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a built-in.

```
FluentActions.Invoking(() => new Foo(null)).ShouldThrow<ArgumentNullException>();
```